# Ruby on Rails: Got error for application.js file, Sprockets::FileNotFound in Pins#index

Tags: jquery, ruby, jquery-masonry

Sprockets::FileNotFound in Pins#index

Showing /Users/Paris/code/omrails/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

couldn't find file 'jquery.masonry.pkgd.js'
  (in /Users/Paris/code/omrails/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)

Extracted source (around line #6):

```
3:  <head>
4:    <title>One Month Rails</title>
5:    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:  </head>
9:  <body>
```

Here is:

application.html.erb =>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>One Month Rails</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= render 'layouts/header'%>
        <div class="container">
                 <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
                <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
         <% end %>
            <%= yield %>
            <%= render 'layouts/footer'%>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1.0'
end
```

GitHub:
https://github.com/parisliahyun/omrails.git

I've been stuck on this forever, of course I'm very new to Ruby. All help appreciated!

Comment: Having looked at your github repository: in your application.js you are referencing "jquery.masonry.pkgd.js" but in your folder the file is named "masonry.pkgd.js". Change the line in application.js to match the filename.

Comment: That fixed it. (I feel silly.) Thank you SO MUCH for your help. :)